# class -(MyAnnotation annotation) was deallocated

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit

> An instance 0x11d0ce4b0 of class -(MyAnnotation annotation) was
>   deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.
>   Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached
>   to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop
>   here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:

But I have put a **breakpoint** on my dealloc method, and in there, I do deregister for those notifications. Dealloc is called, and I did check that it was the same object, and all the calls to deregister are there. So I don't know how it could *not* be removing the observers.

Comment: Did you happen to register them twice by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom `AnnotationView`:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface AnnotationView : MKPlacemark

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *subtitle;


@end
```

And in `.m file`

```
#import "AnnotationView.h"

@implementation AnnotationView

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate addressDictionary:(NSDictionary *)addressDictionary
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:addressDictionary]))
    {
        self.coordinate = coordinate;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

// Use Annotation Add `#import "AnnotationView.h"` in your relevant `.m file`:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pCoordinate ;
pCoordinate.latitude = LatValue;
pCoordinate.longitude = LanValue;

// Create Obj Of  AnnotationView class  

AnnotationView *annotation = [[AnnotationView alloc] initWithCoordinate:pCoordinate addressDictionary:nil] ;

    annotation.title = @"I m Here";
    annotation.subtitle = @"This is Sub Tiitle";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

**Above is simple Example of how to create `AnnotationView`.**