# Custom annotation callout view is not displayed properly

Tags: iphone

I have a custom annotation callout view in my app.I want mapview to adjust automatically so that annotation callout view is always displayed within visible area.right now it is displayed like shown in image.any solution?
[image]

Comment: what are the csutom call out methods Youu are using.. Are u using these CalloutMapAnnotationView.h

Comment: yes.I am using the same.

Comment: then u must adjust the mapview offset in that class asper your requirement shuchn that it will always come in the mid part bacause u are showing with a small part in mapview  that is.. check

Answer (score 0):

[This is my answer for create Annotation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241156/class-myannotation-annotation-was-deallocated/15241335#15241335)

Call following method for display properly all of annotation in mapview. (*This method call after create annotation*)

```
[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:self.mapView];
```

Code for above method

```
-(void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)mapView
{
    if([mapView.annotations count] == 0)
        return;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
    topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
    topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
    bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

    for(DDAnnotation* annotation in mapView.annotations)
    {
        topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

        bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
        bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    }

    NSLog(@"A%f, B%f, C%f, D%f,", topLeftCoord.latitude, topLeftCoord.longitude, bottomRightCoord.latitude, bottomRightCoord.longitude);

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
    region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;

    region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks iPatel,but my problem is not what you have suggested the solution for.my all the annotations are displayed properly in mapview.but the problem is that when I tapp on any pin,the callout view is opened.My problem is that it does not adjust automaticaly to be shown properly on map view.please see the image I have attached for clarification.